# Passing list parameter in iBatis 2.3.0

Tags: spring, mybatis, ibatis

I am trying to pass a list of type Long to my IBatis xml file. Below is the code:

Java Call:

```
List<Long> a; // This contains a list of id's 
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
params.put("iArray",a);
```

I need to pass this list of id's in my sql, defined on mapper xml as:

select * from students where student_id in (a - list of id's should be passed).

What is the best way to implement this. Kindly help. I'm using iBatis 2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to Pass HashMap. You could pass directly list of studentIds as show below.

```
public List<Student> getStudents(List<String> list);
```

And your Mapper xml would look like as follows.

```
<select id="getStudents" parameterType="list" resultType="Student">
        SELECT * from students where studentId in
        <foreach item="item" collection="list" open="(" separator="," close=")">
            #{item}
        </foreach>
    </select>
```